# SAPUI5: Wizard goToStep() method is not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5, wizard

I am using SAPUI5 Wizard for my company project but it is not working for me for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
var allSteps = oWizardElement.getSteps();
var stepOne = allSteps[0];
var stepTwo = allSteps[1];
var stepThree = allSteps[2];
    if (iActiveStep === 1) {
        oWizardElement.goToStep(stepThree, false);
    }
```

After I ran the code, the entire wizard is broken. Including the header with step 1, steo 2, and step 3 buttons are off...
When I checked the error, in the console it says

```
/webapp/resources/sap/m/library-preload.json/sap/m/WizardProgressNavigator.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

Could someone please guide me what's wrong in my code?

Here's the sources I found in the SAPUI5 documentation: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Wizard.html#getSteps

Comment: That's too little information to go with. It would help if you would have a full stack trace on the debug version of ui5. It would even be better if you could create a minimal viable example on jsbin. Btw, isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600919/sapui5-wizard-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setattribute-of-undefi?

Comment: @jpenninkhof sry it would be difficult cuz it's company code. Maybe u could let me know some possible errors pls? Thanks!

Comment: That's why I mentioned that it would be great to get something minimal viable. It doesn't need to be all your code, just the part that doesn't work. Essentially, you running into an issue in which a variable is not defined, while ui5 expects it to be defined. There could be numerous reasons why that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation say the step you are going to need to be activated. You should have already reached "stepThree" before otherwise gotostep() will not work.

Comment: For anyone wondering. You can use `setCurrentStep(stepId)` to move directly to the step you want.

Answer (score 0):

please remember that you have to write the source in onRouteMatched or onAfterRendering function

Then following the code below.

```
var oFirstStep= this._wizard.getSteps()[0];

            this._wizard.discardProgress(oFirstStep);

            var oCurrStep = this.getView().byId(this._currentStep);//this._currentStep is step you want to nav to

            this._wizard.setCurrentStep(oCurrStep);
```